# Apache Camel return after processing (for outside sheduler)

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, integration

We are using Spring Boot for running Camel routes using Camel Spring Boot starter. We would like to know how to exactly when the processing is done in Camel? The issue is that since we are calling the executable jar file from outside Camel, it needs to know when the Camel processing has been done (say after processing a bunch of files from a directory). If we enable camel.springboot.main-run-controller=true, Camel process never returns and the outside batch process waits indefinitely. If we make camel.springboot.main-run-controller=false, the camel process will return immediately without processing the files (as routes are started in daemon threads). Is there an easier solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure camel spring boot to self terminate after X period of time, X period of being idle, or after processing more than X messages.

You can configure these with the `camel.springboot.XXX` options in the spring application.properties file.

An alternative is to use control bus to stop the route after it has processed all the files etc. But the former may be easier to just say after its been idle for more than 30 seconds etc.

Comment: Thanks Claus for your answer. Where càn I refer the list of spring boot properties available so that I can modify it in my application.properties file? I already have up voted your answer. If this works, that's the perfect solution for us.

Comment: IDEA and potential other IDEs have auto completion so you can press ctrl + space like in source code editor. If not you can find the options in the source code: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-2.21.x/components/camel-spring-boot/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/spring/boot/CamelConfigurationProperties.java

Comment: I tried it and it did not work as expected. Hence sent an empty message once the file component (which was the from endpoint consumer) when no m ore files to pick up. Then used a bean to stop the context

Comment: I want to stop some `route` after the idle timeout period. Is it possible to do in route level instead of `CamelContext`